# Decimal values come NULL when I read them from COBOL file

Tags: apache-spark, cobol

I am trying to read a COBOL file. I have the copybook that defined as following:

```
10  P1  PIC X(02).
10  P2  PIC X(15).
10  P3  PIC X(01).
10  P4  PIC X(01).
10  P5  PIC X(01).
10  P6  PIC X(01).
10  P7  PIC X(01).
10  P8  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P9  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P10  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P11  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P12  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P13  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P14  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P15  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P16  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P17  PIC S9(06)V99.
10  P18  PIC S9(06)V99.
```

The values in `p8` through `p18` contain signed decimal values, but when I check the resulting table they are shown as `NULL`.

**Things that I tried:**

I changed the `S9(06)V99` to:

- `S9(06)V99 USAGE COMP` the **`NULL`** still showing
- `S9(06)V99 USAGE COMP-3` `Spark` job halted
- `S9(06)V99 USAGE COMP-6` `Spark` job halted

Also I tried to change the values to `String` (`PIC X(20)`) but still no luck.

Any help?

***Note:*** as you can see all my attempts were with the COBOL structure, may be some thing that I can do with my SCALA code?

***EDIT 1***

```
val df = ss.read.format("za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.source")
      .option("copybook", Util.getProperty("hdfs_dir") + "/" + Util.getProperty("copyBook"))
      .option("schema_retention_policy", "collapse_root")
      .load("s3a://my-S3-location/");
```

***EDIT 2***

According to one suggestions that I received from a friend, I added the following option to `SparkSession`:

```
.option("floating_point_format", "IBM")
```

Also I tried @mazaneicha  suggestion:

```
.option("encoding", "ascii")
```

***More details***

The program able to read the **regular decimal** (I have couple of columns that have regular decimal), but the problem with the **signed decimal**

[image]

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: I did edit my question and added the code that I tried.

Comment: Have you tried verifying extracted schema? https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix#spark-sql-schema-extraction

Comment: The schema have been verified, and it seems good.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "COBOL file," any more than there is a "C file" or a "Java file."  COBOL is a programming language not a file format.

Comment: COMP, COMP-3, and COMP-6 refer to the format of the data in the file.  You should use whatever was used to write the file.

Comment: You have tagged this question with "mainframe" but refer to COMP-6 which is not valid for IBM Enterprise COBOL.

Comment: Are you running spark on the mainframe or has the file been transferred to a distributed platform?

Comment: Could you add the schema that you've got to your question? Also, please verify the encoding of your data file because _"Cobrix assumes input data is encoded in EBCDIC. You can load ASCII files as well by specifying the following option: .option("encoding", "ascii")."_  I'd expect sign-overlay in decimals to be sensitive to  this.

Comment: Can you provide the data you are processing (in hex) and what do you mean job halted?  Was there an S0c7 abend or other terminating code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never declare an variable as numeric(9) in cobol while reading data from file,
Instead of that declare variables as Alphanumeric (X).

And for further calculation convert the variable to numeric by using **FUNCTION NUMVAL**

Example: 
         RESULT = FUNCTION NUMVAL(P8).